# How many U.S. launch vehicles have failed on initial launch?

Tags: launch, failure, first-flight

I'm doing some research about U.S. launch vehicle failures, and particularly failures occurring during the first vehicle launch.  I'm trying to get some data about how frequently failures like this occur.  I imagine those rates have decreased over time with better mod/sim capabilities, etc.  Any data appreciated.  Thanks, Gil

Comment: Related: [most common causes of 21st century launch failures](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8322/195)

Comment: Do my Estes rockets count? If so the number is quite large...

Comment: @JonCuster I have always maintained that going up in a wild corkscrew still constitutes going up and thus counts as a success.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym - well, it was mainly the powered wild corkscrew coming down that was the issue. That and fire...

Comment: Ah, yes, it is important to keep the pointy end up, flamey end down.